# Infimum of $g(x)=\int_{\ln{(x+1)}}^x t^{-2}e^tdt,x\in(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I am looking for the infimum of
$$g(x)=\int_{\ln{(x+1)}}^x t^{-2}e^tdt,x\in(0,\infty)$$
The first idea is to transform
$$g(x)=\int_{c}^x t^{-2}e^tdt+\int_{\ln{(x+1)}}^c t^{-2}e^tdt=\int_{c}^x t^{-2}e^tdt-\int_{c}^{\ln{(x+1)}} t^{-2}e^tdt$$
This is where I get stuck. I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Can you compute $g'(x)$ through the fundamental Theorem of Calculus, then understand when $g'(x)$ is equal or close to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{1}^{\log(x+1)}e^t\frac{dt}{t^2} = \int_{e}^{x+1}\frac{ds}{\log(s)^2} = \int_{e-1}^{x}\frac{dt}{\log(t+1)^2} $$
hence by the fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
$$ g'(x) = \frac{e^x}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\log(x+1)^2}$$
and it is not difficult to check that $g'(x)>0$ for any $x>0$.
This implies that $g(x)$ is an increasing function and the wanted infimum is indeed
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\int_{\log(x+1)}^{x}\frac{e^{t}}{t^2}\,dx $$
that equals $\frac{1}{2}$, since the integrand function behaves like $\frac{1}{t^2}$ while the length of the integration range behaves like $\frac{x^2}{2}$ when $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: Congratulations for the $200k$ reputation !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I am honored, but it is a bit too soon: I still need 250 rep points or so :)

Comment: Come on, Jack !